# Is it possible to disable Locker Service for Lightning Web Components? (I mean LWC and not Aura Components!)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, locker-service

Is it possible to disable Locker Service for Lightning Web Components? For Aura Components it goes like this:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/security_ls_disable.htm

This works for Aura Components very well and as expected.

Now, how can we disable the Locker Service for a LWC?

Comment: Maybe you can share what it is you are trying to do that requires LS disabled (eventhough i dont believe this is possible with lwc)

Comment: I think it is not possible. locker service could be disabled only if the API version is below 40.0 and LWC is available only starting from API 45.0

Comment: @glls see my comment at JPParadis answer.

Answer (score 2):

In LWC, Lightning Locker is always enabled to enforce code isolation.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.security_locker_service

Are you facing an issue with Locker? We monitor these forums and try to address the concerns as they come up.

Comment: My experience with aura and LockerService was very bad and as a result we did most components in v36.0 having any locker issues out of the way. We usually have to do a lot of DOM manipulations of our own elements with jquery. This works with LockerService somehow but the JS Proxies make debuggin hard and the performance was brutally slow. with v36.0 all is fine. Also we are using stuff like CKEdtior, Cytoscape JS and other huge JS Libs which were hard to make them work even without LS in Aura. But we made it somehow. With LS it would have been either impossible or super slow or too much effort

Comment: btw. with our v36.0 compos we have created also own lightweight containment pattern to e.g. prevent css bleedouts of the compos or unwanted affection of DOM manipulations to sibling compos. but our "micro locker" is way less restrictive and has practicality a zero footprint in terms of performance. it just keeps the guts of the compos to where they belong.

Comment: @UweHeim The immediate option for large libraries is to iframe them. We're also hard at improving Locker performance, so if you have a few examples to post, we will add them to our metrics. We're also removing proxies and your comments show that we are on the right path.

Comment: thanks so much sharing this future looking statement. if you like we could indeed share some examples with you. e.g. screenshots or maybe even a managed package to play around with. Especially direct access to google maps would help. I know the new lightning:map and the iframe approach but we need the full unleashed stuff to succeed

Comment: in fact we have heavily used iframing. but this raises the immediate need for a way more powerful visualforce container as the  your native is. especially automatic height adjustments to the vf-content is a MUST HAVE. also that we've done. again with a v36.0 aura bundle. but the requirements grow and grow in terms of communication via window.sendMessage() which pushes us to recode everything as v36.0. just need to verify that LWC can't do what v36-aura can. good to learn that you understand that the current locker stops lots of people to proceed with components in general...

Comment: @UweHeim, thanks for sharing that feedback. The browser API is large, and we focus on what we hear is important, so please do share your examples. For iframes, we could accelerate the port of lightning:container to LWC: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/container_overview.htm

Comment: for a starter in terms of libraries: 1.) proxy-less usages of jquery to handle the components own DOM (we almost need everything). b) 100% support of https://ckeditor.com/ c) full support of http://js.cytoscape.org/ d) full support of https://www.chartjs.org/ e) full support of goolge maps (markes, layers, everything, geocoding,placesAPI, ...) - puuuhh - it's a lot, but there is even more we need... we gave up on locker a long time ago and went with v36-aura. the good news is: so far v36 rocks like hell! we made incredible things and coding was really productive!

Comment: @JFParadis we're experiencing similar issues, is there a way to contact you directly?

Comment: @JFParadis Can you please add that iframe approach to the LWC documentation page about using Third-Party JavaScript Libraries? It would have saved us a couple months of work had we known that it would have been unusably slow if we tried to use a large library that way.

Comment: @Rozgonyi Unfortunately, I have left Salesforce to pursue new opportunities and I am no loger working on Locker Service and LWC

Comment: For starters, you could fix `Range.setStart()`, a bug in locker which has been outstanding for two years, which hardly fits the definition of "as they come up". If you're going to essentially rewrite the entire DOM API to "improve it", then at a bare minimum you should have extensive unit tests which would of course include the Range API, which would have turned up this and other bugs (such as commonAncestor) before they even shipped.

Comment: requestFullscreen is not working. Any alternative to that