# Loading a Visualforce Page in a LWC using an iFrame while click protection is on

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components, iframe, clickjacking

We have a Visualforce page that uses a large JQuery library that we wrote. We wanted to use that JQuery library in a LWC and so we create a LWC with an iframe that loads the Visualforce page. (We used that approach based on a suggestion in a comment in [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/262514/is-it-possible-to-disable-locker-service-for-lightning-web-components-i-mean-l) due to performance issues we had loading the library directly.)

The LWC loads the Visualforce page fine except when the org has the `Enable clickjack protection for customer Visualforce pages with headers disabled` option checked under `Setup > Session Settings`. The error we get is:

```
Refused to display 'https://...visualforce.com/apex/...' in a frame
because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy
directive: "frame-ancestors 'self' http://*.visualforce.com".`
```

We can load pages with the `lightning.force.com` domain in the iframe fine. So it seems to be because the Visualforce page has a `visualforce.com` domain and so it considers it cross-domain even though its another Salesforce page in the same org. We added `*.visualforce.com` to the "CSP Trusted Sites" and the "Whitelisted Domains for Visualforce Inline Frames" but neither helps. Both the LWC and the Visualforce page are our code and so we can modify them as needed.

Is there any way around this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under `Session Settings` for `Whitelisted Domains for Visualforce Inline Frames` make sure you add the org's base domain (not the visualforce domain). That is the domain that is whitelisted to present the Visualforce iframe.

Example: `https://yourdomainname.lightning.force.com`

Comment: Just wanted to thank @Phil B for the comment. This was a major roadblock for us, and your comment resolved it. Thanks!